# Authorization roles WebAPI oauth owin

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, oauth, authorization, owin

I implemented a token authorization system on ASP.NET Web API with OWIN middleware. I successfully can authenticate with a REST client and obtain an authorization token to call the API. If I put the `[Authorize]` attribute on a GET action in my controller it also works correctly. If I don't have a valid token it denies the resource with a 401 message, but if I use `[Authorize(Roles="admins")]` with the `roles` parameter, it doesn't recognize the user's roles. I verified things in the database and checked that `usersinroles` is correctly filled.

This is a code snippet:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "admins")]
public IEnumerable<CompanyModel> Get()
{
    ClaimsPrincipal principal = Request.GetRequestContext().Principal as ClaimsPrincipal;
    bool isrole = principal.IsInRole("admins");
```

I also checked the action without the `roles` parameter and the `isrole` boolean is always `false`. Do I have to enable something?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You must add in GrantResourceOwnerCredentials method:

```
identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "admins"));
```

---

**Step by step**

In StartUp.cs class, you should have a custom provider, like the line

```
Provider = new CustomAuthorizationServerProvider()
```

for example:

```
public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions oAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
    {
        AllowInsecureHttp = true,
        TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
        AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
        Provider = new CustomAuthorizationServerProvider()
    };

    // Token Generation
    app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(oAuthServerOptions);
    app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
}
```

Then, your CustomAuthorizationServerProvider that inherits from **OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider** class will override **GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)**.

Then, after checking that the user has correct UserName and Password, you must add

```
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
...
// other claims
...
identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "admins"));
...
var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, properties);
context.Validated(ticket);
```

**Edited**

You can get user roles from DB instead of using the "admins" harcoded string doing:

```
var roles = await userManager.GetRolesAsync(userId);
```

So you can add the following method in your repository:

```
public async Task<IList<string>> UserRoles(string userId)
{
    IList<string> roles = await userManager.GetRolesAsync(userId);

    return roles;
}
```

And then call it from your overrided **GrantResourceOwnerCredentials** adding:

```
using (AuthRepository repository = new AuthRepository())
{
    IdentityUser user = await repository.FindUser(context.UserName, context.Password);

    if (user == null)
    {
        context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect");
        return;
    }

    var roles = repository.UserRoles(user.Id);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it almost works but how can i ad claims taken from the user registred roles instead of "admins" fixed string?

Comment: @user2100125 I've edited my answer to retrieve user roles from Db.

Comment: This helped me. Thanks :)

Comment: `[OverrideAuthorization]` is handy where you want to want to specify different Roles at the Action level vs. what you have defined at the Controller level. Nice post [here](https://ramanisandeep.wordpress.com/2017/09/08/override-filters-in-asp-net-web-api-2/#comments)