# C# Authorization roles in web API 2

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2

I have implemented a token based authentication web Api 2 application using OWIN middleware, authentication is made successfully where I can retrieve token and use it to get to the method of the web Api.

However when I tried to add roles authorization, it doesn't work, I've searched thoroughly and found that I have to add in the "GrantResourceOwnerCredentials " in the oAuthorization provider the following:

`identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "the role that i need to add"));`

The above line is all that I can get, it is also found in [Authorization roles WebAPI oauth owin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25661623/authorization-roles-webapi-oauth-owin)

However still whenever I use a token to get to any method(even authorized ones with different role) it still retrieve results normally.

I mean when for example in the API Controller: it is like the following:

```
 [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    // GET api/Patient
    public IQueryable<Patient> GetPatients()
```

while in the "GrantResourceOwnerCredentials" method i have added only an Employee role:

```
var oAuthIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
oAuthIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Employee"));
```

Also, the Table in the server explorer that holds the roles "AspNetUserRoles" is not updated.

What I'm missing???

Comment: Well you are creating claims not roles so the table wouldn't update. Have you tried creating the role manually in the database and adding a reference to a user there?

Comment: @ GirmurD:I have added two roles manually in the database: in Table "ASPNetRules" and updated also assign roles to users using "AspNetUserRoles" Table, but still the same, any token can access the Authorized method stated above.

Comment: Is the user definitiely connected to that role? There should be a AspNetUser, AspNetRoles and AspNetUserRoles table yes? The roles are in the AspNetRoles table and you put a user into a role in the AspNetUserRoles table? Did you do that? Did it make a difference?

Comment: yes.
the register method in the account controller fill AspNetUser Table then i updated the AspNetRoles, and AspNetUserRoles  manually.
as far as i know that when using token authentication, i have to add the role in the form of a claim 
oAuthIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Employee")); //after i have defined the employee role in the tables mentioned earlier.
still any token can get to the method !!!

Comment: Have you tried the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20132795/asp-net-identity-check-user-roles-is-not-working

Comment: Look at this: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/securing-net-core-web-api-identityserver4-resource-owner-dalvandi?trk=mp-author-card