# Owin Authorization denies Roles

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I've recently joined a project team and have been tasked with setting up User Roles for the backend of the project.
It uses ASP.NET C# WebApi with Owin. 
My issue is, when I assign an attribute to the Controller Method like this:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
```

The response is always Authorization denied for this request.
However if I simply use:

```
[Authorize]
```

It works.
Note that I am logging in with a User that has been assigned the Role of Admin.

I've noticed that this question is similar to: [Authorization roles WebAPI oauth owin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25661623/authorization-roles-webapi-oauth-owin)

However, it seems their code in startup.cs is different somehow, or else I'm struggling to follow the answer correctly.

The code in the startup.cs that I have to work with is:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    // configure OAuth
    ConfigureOAuth(app);

    // configure Mvc
    HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
    WebApiConfig.Register(config);
    app.UseWebApi(config);
}

public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
    {
        AllowInsecureHttp = true,
        TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
        AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
        Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider()
    };

    // Token Generation
    app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
    app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
}
```

Is there something else I need to add in here to allow for Roles or should it be somewhere else in the code.
I'm not completely familiar with ASP.NET C# MVC or WebApi, any help is severely appreciated.

Comment: Please show logging logic and where you assign Claims/Roles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider`

you have method like `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials`

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context) {
 await Task.Run(
  () => {
      ...logging logic...
      var loginResult = authRepository.Login(context.UserName, context.Password);
      if (!loginResult.Success) return;
      ...logging logic...

      var claims = new List < Claim > ();
      claims.add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, loginResult.Role)); < --here
      var id = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalBearer);
      context.Validated(id);
  });
}
```

And`loggingResult` is something that is returned by your repository/DAL layer

Comment: great, but how do I find say the ID of the user within this so I can retrieve their role from the DB?

Comment: I edited my answer, you can access context.UserName and context.Password properties

Comment: should I extend the SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider then, or is there a way to override it from within the Startup? also, I don't see no login method in this Repo. I haven't set up this project or backend, I just have to work with it :/

Comment: @Colum Why don't you ask them, how the stuff works! Are these guys your colleagues or your enemies?

Comment: Holiday period... doesnt help. Also, I'm not too sure if they knew exactly what they were doing. I believe it was set up by following a tutorial which didn't go near Roles and Claims

Comment: The assign roles logic should be inside `SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider` as I said. Open it and find how they assign roles, it should be similliar to my answer

Comment: Sorry, finally just worked my way around the code, makes more sense now. thanks